Junction Points in Network Dataset don't work if not located on a centerline vertex
I'm building a network dataset (Network Analyst) for routing purposes.  I need to connect Driveways, which I can edit, and Centerlines, which I cannot edit (see below for explanation...)  I want to use EndPoint connectivity for both feature classes, so I use the Intersect tool to create Junction Points at each intersection that a Driveway intersects a Centerline.
In the Network Dataset, I create 2 different connectivity groups.  I put Centerlines in Group 1 and set to EndPoint connectivity, and I put Driveways in Group 2 and set to EndPoint connectivity.  I put Junction Points in both groups and set the Policy to Override. I essentially treat this as a multi-modal network and followed the directions here: Connectivity explanation
When testing, I find that the routing works as desired, BUT ONLY at places where my Junction Points are on top of a vertex in a centerline.  In other words, when I draw my Driveways, if I snap the endpoint of a driveway to any vertex on a centerline, then routing (through Junction Points) works fine.  However, if there's a long straight centerline that doesn't have many vertices and I snap my driveway to just the EDGE of the centerline, then routing does not work, even though a Junction Point is present at the intersection of those 2 features.
In the Connectivity explanation, there is a single sentence that says: "...but often you will want to place the bus stop at an intermediate vertex."  In my situation, my Junction Points would serve the same purpose as "bus stops".  Therefore, does that mean that my Junction Points NEED to be located on top of a VERTEX in a centerline, or should this be considered a bug in Network Analyst?  My thought is that since I'm setting my connectivity policy up as "Override" that Junction Points should be able to be placed anywhere along a centerline, but that is not the behavior I am getting at the present.
(NOTE: I can't "edit" the centerlines, as these are centerlines that I download on a monthly basis, and would require me to edit them every single time I do an update.  I'm just trying to avoid someone answering "well, just add vertices to your centerlines..."

Split centerline by end points of driveways. Much faster than adding vertex, which you can't do anyway. Split lines at points tool is reliable

The centerlines are used in a 911 mapping application, and having duplicate segments with the same attributes will not work. There are some centerline segments that would get split into 15-20 parts, all with identical attributes...

Dissolve them back to eingle lines

Or use basic script to modify existing line in place. Searching this forum you'll find multiple answers. All of them are too complex in my opinion. If of interest I can post my own
